# Notepad++ Insert characters every 2 characters of a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a string representing hex numbers, like this:

```
778206213082061D06092A
```

I want to get a string like this:

```
0x77, 0x82, 0x06, 0x21, 0x30, 0x82, 0x06, 0x1D, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2A
```

So every 2 characters, I want to insert `, 0x`
Is this doable with Notepad++?

Comment: Yes, use macros - see https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2013/10/27/notepad-macros-a-basic-example/ for example.

Comment: Any 2 characters or any alphanumeric or any ALLCAPS + digit? It would be best to show what you tried.

Comment: Thanks. But I just found a very simple solution: Find: `(..)` and replace with `\1, 0x`

Comment: This will add `,` and a space before the first value on the line.

Comment: I noticed, though I can fix this manually.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

**Find:**

```
(..)
```

**Replace:**

```
0x\1,
```

The find expression `(..)` matches any two characters (dot matches anything), and the parenthesis allow us to *capture* those two characters.  We can then replace with the hex expression, accessing those two captured characters by using `\1` (or `$1`; Notepad++ will accept either).  Note that there is a space after the comma in the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(..)`
- Replace with: `0x$1,`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

You have then to remove the last `,` if requested.

Comment: Posted approximately 15 seconds before me :-) +1

Comment: This can be done without having to remove the final `,`. Just do not add it. Use a conditional replacement pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:Certainly, but I can't find a simple way to not add it :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl+H for Find & Replace
2. Tick *Regular Expression*
3. Find: `([A-Z0-9]{2})` & replace with `0x\1,` (space on the end)
4. Find: `, $` & replace with nothing. (to remove trailing `,`)